# Change Ubuntu screen size with virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7, fullscreen

I'm using VM VirtualBox 4.3.18 to run Ubuntu. It works fine, just that a few days ago I started seeing the screen of Ubuntu smaller (previous to that it was on full screen, and I can't recall changing anything). How can I fit it back to full screen?

Note: When I say 'full screen' I don't mean that I don't want to see the VirtualBox's task bar, so CTRL+F is not the solution I'm looking for (with CTRL+F my screen stayed small) . CTRL+C doesn't seem to work either; it gives me a screen in the desired size, but it's distorted.

Comment: You may have not installed DKMS but there was a kernel update. You then will have to reinstall the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm). No need for the extension pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install guest additions and extension pack first

Second select 'view' then select 'resize to match' option

this will make full screen a true full screen.

If you need help locating any of the files let me know.

Comment: The extension pack is not needed for this.

Comment: Thanks @MHK, just before I try these installations: I installed Ubuntu a few weeks ago and I started having the small screen only a few days ago. Are you aware of any solution that doesn't involve further installations? I'm asking because, as I said, it used to work properly. Thanks again :)

Comment: nope..you do need those two installed to get all the functionality of virtualbox anyways.